# XSL:FO border-style dotted

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I am trying to add a dotted line inside a table.  I 
    Below is the XSLT . When I use the `border-style = "dotted"`  the line appears as a solid line  and not a dotted line.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:m="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="hello" page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in" />
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>

      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="hello">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <fo:block>
            <fo:tab le width="100mm">
              <fo:table-column/>
              <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block border-before-style="dashed" border-before-width="1mm" border-before-width.length="1pt">sdsdasd</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
              </fo:table-body>
              </fo:table>
          </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>

    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is the dotted style not supported in XSL-FO.  I am using FONET.dll for .Net

Comment: Which processor (XEP, XSLFormatter, FOP, ....) are you using to create the final output?

Comment: I am using FONET.dll for .Net

Comment: FO.NET is based on a very old version of Apache FOP and has not been maintained for several years. https://fonet.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FO.NET started as a port of Apache FOP 0.20.4 to the .NET environment.

That version of FOP did not support the whole FO standard, the different border styles being among the unsupported features.